# Syntax error with "welcome message" when importing script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just starting to teach myself how to use Python, and installed it yesterday. Following a textbook example (Python Programming, John Zelle), I created a simple program, entitled chaos.py. It is written exactly as the book has it. Upon importing this into Python, I got the following error:

```py
>>> import chaos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\chaos.py", line 1
    Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As far as I can tell, it seems to be having an issue with the "welcome message" at the beginning of the script, and I'm not sure why. I have tried several other programs and have gotten the same result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In python scripts, the python interpreter doesn't need to be specified. Delete the line with `Python 3.7.3 (...` and you should be ok

Comment: I'm not sure why you would have that text in your Python file outside of a comment...  regardless, the exception is telling you exactly what and where the problem is. For future reference, though, putting the code that's causing the issue in your question is important to make it much more likely that we can figure out what's causing any given problem.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I've sorted out the issue.